# Android different sensor delays for different time with the same rate set

Tags: android, delay

I've set the same sampling rates (delays) for different sensors, like:

```
    Sensor GSensor = sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, GSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    Sensor FSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, FSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    Sensor MAGNETICSensor = sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, MAGNETICSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

But the rate of receiving messages from MAGNETIC Sensor is much higher than that of the other two sensors.

Why is this, and can I slower the rate of MAGNETIC Sensor?

Here is the test log, where A,M,G respectively represent ACCELERATION, MAGNETIC AND GRAVITY sensor:

```
07-30 10:37:03.314: D/mtest(32598): G
07-30 10:37:03.314: D/mtest(32598): A
07-30 10:37:03.314: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.334: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.354: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.374: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.394: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.414: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.434: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.454: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.474: D/mtest(32598): M
07-30 10:37:03.494: D/mtest(32598): G
07-30 10:37:03.494: D/mtest(32598): A
07-30 10:37:03.494: D/mtest(32598): M
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Docs - The delay is only a hint to the system. events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate.

I'd suggest you to try out the various available options  and choose the one that works best with your requirements.

1. SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
2. SENSOR_DELAY_UI
3. SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
4. SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST.

If nothing works, you can write your own filter inside the sensor listener which discards values which come faster than you'd want it to, by comparing timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Different sensors sample at different rates due to physics.  I'm not sure if you really want to slow it down, it depends on how accurate you want to be.  But yes, you used SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL so you can always pick something slower.  Also from API 9 on you can use a millisecond value for rate if you want.